# FilenotFoundException java file android

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, filenotfoundexception

```
        File fXmlFile = new File("D:\\Praias.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

and my file is at D:\

Why i'm having that exception?

**Log**

```
  W/System.err(  845): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /D:/Praias.xml
  W/System.err(  845):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OS
  FileSystem.java:244)
  W/System.err(  845):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:7
  7)
  W/System.err(  845):    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuild
  er.java:138)
  W/System.err(  845):    at inescporto.seawatch.BeachesParser.parserXML(BeachesPa
  rser.java:36)
```

Comment: Sorry to point out the obvious, but are you CERTAIN the files exists - spelt correctly and with the same case?

Comment: is the line you posted the line it's breaking on?

Comment: @ DwB Already tried with D:/Praias.xml
@jazzbassrob yes, i'm sure.

Comment: how about file:///d:/Praias.xml? Also check if(fXmlFile.exists()) before you do any operation.

Comment: Rename your file with **`Praias.xml`**

Comment: @unpix CAn you show us some more code/

Comment: the file is Praias.xml , i will show you more, editing the post

Comment: write a simple java test that creates a File object.  see if you can open it in the test.  that will narrow your possible error locations.

Comment: @DwB can you explain me better what to do? Because i'm not able to create a File object because i'm getting that exception.

Comment: @unpix You can create a `File` object because you have done it in your code, and the exception is on a later line.  Try calling `fXmlFile.exists()` and see what the result is.

Comment: What are you running on? Windows?

Comment: @jazzbassrob is saying that doesn't exist the file.

I don't if it's because of that I'm getting the error but I'm working with a AndroidProject.

SotiriosDelimanolis yes, my os is Windows

Comment: Is there such a thing as a `D` drive in Android file system? I think not.

Comment: @unpix So you are trying to access a file on your local hard disk in an Android project?

Comment: Exactly, you are correct. So how can i access the file from the project folder? It's not possible?

Comment: as just noted above, if you run this in the android emulator, it will fail because there is no d: drive on the phone.

Comment: It is not possible with the File interface.

Comment: if you need to read a file on a phone, then the file must be on the phone in a known location.  if it is just a project configuration file, then put the file in the classpath and load it via the class path.

Comment: Can you post the output of d: and dir. I doubt the extensions are hidden...

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I think i already know the answer for my initial question.

Comment: @unpix then you should post that answer and mark it as such if it hasn't already been posted.  This will help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Well some OS have problems when you keep a file directly under the Computer drive. Try keeping the file inside a directory. Also to be safe use forward slash (/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, i was trying to open a file in directory D:\ when i was programming one Android Application, so you can easily notice that such directory doesn't exist in android device.